# Elimination of extra characters in a word

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm doing a project which requires removal of extra letters in a word.

If a letter occurs three or more times consecutively, we condense it to one letter

```
-Happyyyyyy -> Happy
-awwwsum -> awsum
-cooool -> col
```

I'm using Ruby 1.8.7 to do this. How do I go about this?

Comment: you need a dictionary data base for this task !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how you do it:

```
result = subject.gsub(
    /(.)   # Match a single character, capture it in group 1
    \1{2,} # Match the same character 2 or more times, as many as possible/x, 
   '\1')   # Replace with the one captured character
```

Result:

```
> subject = "happyyyy daaaaays!!!"
=> "happyyyy daaaaays!!!"
> result = subject.gsub(/(.)\1{2,}/, '\1')
=> "happy days!"
```

Comment: May be worth mentioning that this won't work with stuff like "happyy" or "awwsum", where there's fewer than 3 duplicates.

Comment: for fewer than 3 dupes, use `(.)\1+` . @Rawing he answered according to the op needs.

Comment: @AvinashRaj - we can use what Rawing said to condense the duplicates in a  word to just 2. and then use /(.)\1+ / to match end duplicates . but how do we replace it with just one letter ?

can i use subject.gsub(/(.)\1 /, '\1 ') ??

Comment: @Rawing
we can use what you said to condense the duplicates in a  word to just 2. and then use /(.)\1+ / to match end duplicates . but how do we replace it with just one letter ?

can i use subject.gsub(/(.)\1 /, '\1 ') ??

Comment: same, `subject.gsub(/(.)\1+/, '\1')`